# how to use html5 audio player to play single song whose content is divided into an array of urls?

Tags: javascript, html5, audio, angular.js

I get multiple urls for same song
url1 -> first 5 sec of song
url2 -> next 15 sec of song
and so on
I have to use them to play the song without any lag.
Is it possible using html5 audio ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Questions regarding [development and coding](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are best asked over at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).